# Emacs 26-1 Problems : find-file and neotree

Tags: window-splitting, find-file, neotree

**The Problems:**

I just did a full re-install to Fedora 29, which included the `dnf install emacs`
command.  This installed emacs 26-1; formerly I was using emacs 25.2.  Formerly,
my emacs initialization concluded with :

```
(neotree-dir "/home/steve/")
;
(eww-open-file "~/emacs/neotree/EmacsWiki: Neo Tree.html")
(find-file "~/notes/notes_todo.txt")
(find-file "~/emacs/mywork/notes_todo.txt")
(find-file "~/emacs/mywork/elisp_notes_todo.txt")
(find-file "~/notes/notes_movies_to_download.txt")
(find-file "~/notes/notes_watched_tv.txt")
(find-file "~/math/misc/complex_analysis_01.tex")
```

In emacs 25.2, this worked fine, with the `neotree` attached to the frame.  In 
emacs 26-1, the frame is split horizontally
into two windows, with the last file opened in the bottom window.  Further, when
I navigate to the frame's bottom window, and then execute <kbd>C-x 1</kbd> 
`(delete-other-windows)`, the neotree is also deleted.  In emacs 25.2, the neotree
would not be deleted here.

Also, *sometimes* when I open a file, it splits the frame into two windows rather
than simply switching to the new file's buffer.  I haven't been able to track
down the pattern behind this behavior, so I can't be more precise here.

**My kludgy temporary initialization workaround:**

```
(eww-open-file "~/emacs/neotree/EmacsWiki: Neo Tree.html")
(find-file "~/notes/notes_todo.txt")
(find-file "~/emacs/mywork/notes_todo.txt")
(find-file "~/emacs/mywork/elisp_notes_todo.txt")
(find-file "~/notes/notes_movies_to_download.txt")
(find-file "~/notes/notes_watched_tv.txt")
(find-file "~/math/misc/complex_analysis_01.tex")
;
(delete-other-windows)
;
(neotree-dir "/home/steve/")
```

This resolves initialization but **does not resolve** the subsequent **undesired**
splitting of a frame into windows.  Also, it **does not resolve preserving neotree**
when I delete a window from a split frame.

**My Research**

In emacs 25.2, the relevant code was :

```
(defun find-file (filename &optional wildcards)
"..."
    (interactive
        (find-file-read-args "Find file: "
                (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))
    (let ((value (find-file-noselect filename nil nil wildcards)))
        (if (listp value)
            (mapcar 'switch-to-buffer (nreverse value))
        ;;else : this comment added by me
            (switch-to-buffer value))))
```

In emacs 26.1, the relevant code is :

```
(defun find-file (filename &optional wildcards)
"..."
    (interactive
        (find-file-read-args "Find file: "
                (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))
    (let ((value (find-file-noselect filename nil nil wildcards)))
        (if (listp value)
            (mapcar 'pop-to-buffer-same-window (nreverse value))
        ;;else : this comment added by me
            (pop-to-buffer-same-window value))))
```

Either:
1. I have misunderstood the purpose of `(pop-to-buffer-same-window)` or
2. `(pop-to-buffer-same-window)` is not working as intended.

When I examine the emacs 26.1 code, I see **no pertinent variables** that I could
initialize that would affect the code's behavior.

I did find `28.17 Dedicated Windows` in the elisp manual.  However, if this can
solve my problems, any attempt by me to use this without guidance would be 
blundering in the dark.

**What I Want:**

1. When I open a file, I **never** want the frame to split into windows.  If I
   desire a split, I will subsequently execute <kbd>C-x 2</kbd> `(split-window-below)`.
2. When I have neotree attached to a frame and my frame is also split into windows, when
   I use <kbd>C-x 1</kbd> `(delete-other-windows)`, I **never** want the neotree
   deleted.  If I subsequently want to delete the neotree, I will execute 
   `(neotree toggle)`.

**Addendum**

Just exchanged emails with emacs-gnu-support, re possible bugs.  My main problem was that I needed to change to the most recent copy of neotree.  This change resolved most of my problems.  Now, <kbd>C-x 1</kbd> `(delete-other-windows) does **not** delete the neotree.  I reported an underlying *anomaly* that (I think) might reasonably be construed as **not a bug.** Replication:

1. At the end of your initialization, have find-file open a file, and **then** invoke neotree.
2. **Without mouse-clicking in the buffer area,** use the mouse to take the <kbd>menu <-> buffers</kbd> menu option, and then use the mouse to open a file.

The frame will split into windows, perhaps because the `pop-to-buffer-same-window` function regards the frame as *belonging* to neotree.

Comment: Yes, they are purging the Emacs sources of non-interactive uses of `switch-to-buffer`. It's possible that you have a case where the simple replacement of it by `pop-to-buffer-same-window` does not do the right thing - at least not what you expect/want. You might consider filing a bug report about this case: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew Interesting, thanks.  I did file a bug report.

Comment: @Drew I would welcome your response to **both** this link:https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46075/downgrading-emacs as well as this link: https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/537/are-questions-about-the-os-package-manager-on-topic-when-the-package-in-question

Comment: I don't have much to say about either, mainly because I don't build Emacs and I don't use it on GNU/Linux (unfortunately). I use it on MS Windows, given a Windows binary. I know very little about the questions raised on those pages. That said, in my ignorance about such things *I'd think that questions about building, installing, upgrading, downgrading, etc. Emacs would be on topic here*. (But I won't be contributing to them because of my unfamiliarity.) Off-topic would be questions that dig into the OS beyond such Emacsy questions.

Comment: Can you post your own answer to this question and mark it as the solution?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 the interface is not letting me post an answer to my own question.  The resolution was twofold: 1) if you are running emacs 26-1 and using neotree, upgrade your neotree to the latest version.  2) Realize that if when you invoke neotree, its window is **dedicated**.  Apparently, when the `pop-to-buffer-same-window` function encounters a dedicated window, and tries to open a file on a frame, it will split the frame into windows.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 The workaround to this is (2a) in your emacs initialization, have neotree come **after**  any `find-file` commands and (2b) simply be careful in your workflow to not open a file just after you neotree-toggled onto a frame without first mouse-clicking in the file, in the frame.  Personally, I consider (2b) much ado about nothing.  I mention it only to give you a technical understanding of the `pop-to-buffer-same-window` behavior.