# Downgrading Emacs in Fedora via 'dnf'

Tags: install, version-support, fedora

My problems with emacs 26-1 are discussed at this link :
[Emacs 26-1 Problems : find-file and neotree](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46072/emacs-26-1-problems-find-file-and-neotree)

The following link discusses using `dnf` to installing a previous version of a package:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266888/can-i-force-dnf-to-install-an-old-version-of-a-package

I'm a fedora semi-newbie who just did a full install of Fedora 29, that included
`dnf install emacs`, which installed emacs 26-1.  I would like to **revert** to 
emacs 25-2 (or alternatively any version of emacs 25).  Is there a **clean**
way of (*in effect*) backing out the emacs 26-1 install and then installing a previous
version of emacs?  If so, it would help if I was given the **exact bash commands**
to use.

**Resolution**

I just posted an **Addendum** to the end of my original question at this link:[Emacs 26-1 Problems : find-file and neotree](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46072/emacs-26-1-problems-find-file-and-neotree)

I worked with emacs-gnu-support to resolve most of the problems, so I no longer need to downgrade.  I think that the meta posting at [Are questions about the OS package-manager on-topic when the package in question is Emacs?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/537/454) raises interesting issues, even though (for me) they are now moot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really about package management on a particular OS (Fedora).  Emacs seems like it would be incidental to this problem/solution.

Comment: But I've queried that on Meta: https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/537/454

Comment: @phils I responded to the Meta-posting.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may consider this: Emacs is very much system-independent, so, you don't really need to fear about incompatibility of older versions with newer system. Also, you can run multiple versions of Emacs on the same machine: sometimes this may cause problems with ELisp packages, but nothing that cannot be solved. Emacs isn't a difficult project to build: you can just go with `dnf builddep emacs` and then cloning Emacs Git repository and building from it.

Comment: Have you tried asking at the [Fedora project's SE-like site](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/questions/)?

Comment: @Dan "have you tried..." to what purpose?  Regardless of what they say, either in favor of a subtle workaround, or against, **I could not trust it.**  I can only trust a response from someone very knowledgeable in emacs.

Comment: @wvxvw Very interesting comment, thanks; the plot **thickens**.

Comment: The purpose is that you are asking how to a) uninstall a package via fedora's `dnf` and b) install an earlier version of that package with `dnf`.  That's all about the distro's package manager, so you should ask the people who use the distro.  If you don't want to mess around with that, just remove the fedora package and build from source, which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Dan Yes, but I am also asking what unforseen complications other emacs users have experienced using dnf to uninstall an emacs package.  This is the whole point of my posting, and Fedora.Org is **not** the place to get a reliable answer to that question.  The **reliable** answer is **hidden** in the life-experience of very experienced emacs-users.  Also, as a Fedora semi-newbie, I'm not qualified to judge the wisdom of **manually** removing the emacs package....Other than that, I think that we should agree to disagree.

Comment: You are free to vote to reopen and see if enough other users agree with you.  If 5 users vote to reopen, it will be reopened.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 If you mean an answer to the *underlying question*, please see the addendum that I added to the end of my question at this link: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46072/emacs-26-1-problems-find-file-and-neotree.  **However,** if you (alternatively) mean **this** posting, **the question is unanswered** and I **welcome responses.**  As I indicated in the **Resolution** that I added to the end of my question, although I have not yet gotten an answer, the question has become (**still very worthwhile** but) moot, re I worked with emacs-gnu-suppt to answer the underlying question

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 the closest that anyone has come to answering this question is the **comment from wvxvw**, which I consider very intriguing.

Comment: @zugzwang well, my comment was about your other question, so I deleted it from this one and moved it there.

Comment: I think that as this question stands now, it's many questions in one. I think it would help people answer if it was explained _why_ downgrading Emacs could be problematic. Some thoughts are more Fedora-specific, and some are more Emacs-specific. It's hard to answer this question because it's so broad and nonspecific.

Comment: @zck interesting response, thanks.  For me, the problems in downgrading Emacs resolve to 2 questions:  1.  Using dnf, what is the explicit bash command that one would use to cleanly remove the just installed emacs (+ any dependencies), restoring the fedora 29 system to its state just before installing emacs?  Included in this question would be life experiences from experienced emacs users re explicit additional tasks needed to verify/ensure that the uninstall is **clean.**  Continued on next comment...

Comment: @zck 2. Given that the vanilla dnf install emacs now installs emacs 26.1 into fedora 29, assuming that the uninstall in previous comment has gone cleanly, if one wanted (for example) to now use dnf to install emacs 25.2, what is the explicit bash command (or explicit steps) needed to do so.  As in question 1, this question would (hopefully) also involve wisdom from the life experiences of experienced emacs users.

Comment: @zck the two previous comments being said, I agree with your point; even if one had the wisdom, this is a difficult question to attack.  However, from my perspective, posing this question at unixSE is clearly superior to posing it at Fedora.org.

Comment: Correction to last comment... intended ...posing this question at emacsSE...

Comment: I think a lot of the difficulty is because it seems that other people are coming from the perspective of "package managers work most of the time", and your question seems to be coming from _not trusting_ the package manager, and needing to verify it's "clean", or thinking it's likely there will be "unforseen complications". If you can explain what kinds of problems you think you'll run into, and why, then we could help.

Also, just trying it would really help. If it works, you don't need to ask everyone for all the possible problems. If it doesn't, you'll have a specific problem.

Comment: @zck beating dead horse.  My trying it first is akin to blundering in the dark.  I am hoping to elicit responses from **people who have actually used dnf to uninstall an emacs version and then used dnf to install a prior version.**  From such a person, I would like to know, re their **personal experiences**, what unforseen problems occurred.  **Interesting that no one shared an on point experience, complete with explicit bash commands and a discussion of the problems that they encountered.**  The closest on this webpage is the comment of wvxvw.

Comment: Ok. I just don't see why you need to spend so much time investigating before trying this out. You're asking a difficult question to answer because so few people have done that. You're asking a difficult question because it comes from a viewpoint that most people don't have. You're asking a lot from random people on the internet, seemingly without doing the basic work to figure it out yourself. I hope you get an answer, but I would not be surprised if you don't.

Comment: @zck If this was a math question, then it would be reasonable for me to first try to solve it on my own and then post a query, showing my work and asking for help.  However, in this situation, it is plausible that any **try** on my part will mess up my system, causing me to have to spend another 10 hours re-installing everything.

Comment: I don't think it's as plausible as you do, and that's a big part of the disconnect here. Do you ask for help every time you need to install or uninstall a program? Why this one specifically? Also, I suspect people have spent more than ten hours discussing this issue.

Comment: @zck if it is straightforward, why hasn't there been a response with explicit instructions?  If people are discussing it, that means that there is something to discuss.  I think that we should agree to disagree about the appropriateness of my approach.

Comment: Because this isn't a dnf forum? And "how do I uninstall emacs and install an old version" is a question that you could easily search for. There's a plethora of documentation online about the basic ways; it seems something like `dnf remove emacs; dnf install emacs-25.2` or whatever the right version is will work.

Comment: @zck *it seems something like...* is not a gamble that I would want to take **cold** with my system.  If I remember correctly, when I installed emacs 26.1 on top of fedora 29, there were several pieces of dependent software that were also installed.  If I back out emacs 26.1, **do I also back out the "dependencies"?**  What if I installed a subsequent (unrelated) piece of software that is using one of those dependencies?  Will I be (inadvertantly) breaking the subsequent piece of software?  see next comment.

Comment: @zck Further, even assuming that emacs was the last piece of software that I installed, how reliable is dnf for identifying the associated dependencies to **also uninstall?**  How *clean* will the resulting uninstall be?  Further, if I then install a previous version of emacs, with **its** dependencies, how will this affect **random current 3rd party software?**  It seems **obvious** to me that there is no substitute for interrogating the specific life experiences of others.

Comment: @zck I'm having fun; are you having fun?